# Using sed to extract multiple occurrences in a string to array?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

How to get all matches into a Bash array using sed?

My input is

```
<node><system_id>app1261.works.com</system_id><name>app1261</name></node><node><system_id>app1361.works.com</system_id><name>app1361</name></node><node><system_id>app1461.works.com</system_id><name>app1461</name></node>
```

Output expected stored in array

```
app1261.works.com 
app1361.works.com 
app1461.works.com
```

I am trying the command below but it always returns the last match instead of all matches.

```
sed -ne '{s/.*<system_id>\(.*\)<\/system_id>.*/\1/p;q;}' <<< "$xml"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: With valid XML: `mapfile -t array < <(xmlstarlet select --template --value-of "//name" file.xml)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `gnu grep` then use this look arounds based solution:

```sh
grep -Po '(?<=<system_id>)[^<>]+(?=</system_id>)' <<< "$xml
app1261.works.com
app1361.works.com
app1461.works.com
```

Otherwise, a `grep + sed` solution:

```sh
grep -Eo '<system_id>([^<>]+)</system_id>' <<< "$xml | 
sed -E 's~</?system_id>~~g'

app1261.works.com
app1361.works.com
app1461.works.com
```

Comment: Yep, that's the winner, I was trying to suss it out but drawing blanks. Good job.